# Surjectivity of stalks of holomorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry

Let $X=\mathbb{C}$ with the classical topology, let $\mathcal{O}_X$ be the sheaf of holomorphic functions, and let $\mathcal{O}^*_X$ be the sheaf of invertible (nowhere $0$) holomorphic functions. I'd like to understand why $\rm exp: \mathcal{O}_X\rightarrow \mathcal{O}^*_X$ is an epimorphism.

Since $\rm exp$ is an epimorphism if and only if it is surjective on the stalks, we can consider the induced map $\rm exp:\mathcal{O}_{X_p}\rightarrow \mathcal{O}^*_{X_p}$. So let $(f,U)\in\mathcal{O}^*_{X_p}$. We would like to find a $g(z)\in\mathcal{O}_{X_p}$ such that $\rm exp (g(z))=f(z)$ on some open neighborhood $V$ of $p$ contained in $U$.

Now, perhaps the answer to this is a result in complex analysis that I'm unaware of. What I'd like to know is: why is this true, and how can surjectivity fail if we look at the level of sections instead of stalks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surjectivity on stalks is a consequence of the fact that you can define (a branch of) $\log (f(z))$ in a neighborhood. It fails to be surjective on global sections because $\log$ cannot be globally defined as a single-valued function (the analytic continuation around the origin gives rise to a discrepancy of $2\pi i$).